# Determining resolution

Tags: image-processing

I just read something about this:

> Today Digital IP Camera Resolution is defined by the horizontal (H)
>   and vertical (V) number of pixels (i.e. 640 x 480) or by the total
>   number of pixels in the sensor (H x V = 336K Pixels).

How is the calculation of HxV=336K pixels?

Is H = 640 and V = 480?
If yes doesn't the calculation suppose to be 307200 =~ 307K?

Comment: You're right, they're wrong. Just bad math. Unless there's something more going on (extra sensor elements beyond the image boundaries, for example).

Comment: My gosh. I was trying to understand it. Thanks @Michael for clarify it.